# Extract Text from Span Element via XPath [Selenium]

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="a-row a-spacing-small a-size-small">
<div class="a-row">
<a class="a-link-normal a-declarative g-visible-js reviewStarsPopoverLink" href="#" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover="{"closeButton":"false","url":"/gp/customer-reviews/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=wl_it_o_cm_cr_acr_img_hz?ie=UTF8&a=B05555JQP&contextId=wishi&link=1&seeall=1","name":"review-hist-pop.B075555RJQP","max-width":"700","position":"triggerBottom","data":{"itemId":"I2555555554GT","isGridViewInnerPopover":""},"header":"","cache":"true"}">
<i id="review_stars_I2J55555554GT" class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5">
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.5 out of 5 stars</span>
</i>
<i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"/>
</a>
<a class="a-link-normal g-visible-no-js" href="/product-reviews/B075555JQP/ref=wl_it_o_cm_cr_acr_txt_hz?ie=UTF8&colid=2K4U5555551D&coliid=I2J5555555T&showViewpoints=1">
<span class="a-letter-space"/>
<a id="review_count_I2J55555555GT" class="a-link-normal" href="/product-reviews/B05555555P/ref=wl_it_o_cm_cr_acr_txt_hz?ie=UTF8&colid=255555555D&coliid=I2555555GT&showViewpoints=1">(68)</a>
</div>
<div class="a-row">
<div class="a-row a-size-small itemAvailability">
<div class="a-row itemUsedAndNew">
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract the value `4.5 out of 5 stars` via one of the following XPath:

```
.//*[contains(@id,'review_stars')]/span[@class='a-icon-alt']
.//*[contains(@id,'review_stars')]
```

However, everything that I've tried so far has failed (returns empty String)

The funny thing is that all of these XPaths actually work in `Firebug` so I'm not sure why it isn't working in my program (I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the rating isn't actually visible in browser unless you hover over a specific element but I'm not sure if/why/how this would cause the above mentioned problem and how to fix it)

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried .//*[contains(@class,'a-icon-alt')] ?

Comment: yes, same problem

Comment: Can we have a link to the site?  You may have more than one element that matches that xpath is my guess.

Comment: alright can you also try .getAttribute("innerHTML")  on the element

Answer (score 0):

You failed to include the image  between the anchor  and span.  The span is inside the image, not a sibling of the anchor.

try:

```
.//*[contains(@id,'review_stars')]/i/span[@class='a-icon-alt']
```

Comment: When is `<i>` an image?  It's the html tag for italicized.  ;)

Comment: Wow... my bad.  nice catch.  You're quite correct, <img> is not <i>.  I need more caffeine.

Answer (score 0):

To  extract the value `4.5 out of 5 stars` through `XPath` you can use :

```
//a[@class='a-link-normal a-declarative g-visible-js reviewStarsPopoverLink']/i[starts-with(@id,'review_stars_') and @class='a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5']/span[@class='a-icon-alt']
```

---

### Update :

As you mentioned **`This does not work either. I just tried it.`** you must have missed out a part from the **`xpath`** which I have provided. My Answer was a proven one. See the snapshot below :

[image: XPath_snapshot]

> **Note** : Though your question was related to **`xpath`** you have pulled out your answer with respect to **getText()** method and **getAttribute("innerHTML")** method. How ever my Answer will be working with both **getText()** and **getAttribute("innerHTML")** method.

Comment: `does not work` doesn't throws any light towards whats happening wrong. You need to update the Question with your code trial and error stack trace so volunteers can help you out.

Comment: Well it just returns empty String. You can take a look at my answer to see what works so far (but the main question still stands)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. However `String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal a-declarative g-visible-js reviewStarsPopoverLink']/i[starts-with(@id,'review_stars_') and @class='a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5']/span[@class='a-icon-alt']")).getText();
  System.out.println(text);` yields empty String. I double checked the XPath - I copied it correctly. As I said in my question, all of my XPath work fine in Firebug so it makes sense it's working in whatever program you are using. You need to test it in Java & Selenium. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer my own question although I do not entirely understand why my previous code isn't working. If someone could provide me with an in depth explanation I will accept their answer as the final answer.

For now this is what works for me:

Instead of calling `element.getText();` call `element.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

This returns the correct result but I would like to understand why getText() does not work in this case. Again, if someone could provide an XPath that works or could provide explanation to all this I will accept it as the final answer.

Thanks

Comment: This was already made as a comment in your original question by @Moe Ghafari

Comment: To answer your question though, Selenium is designed to imitate user input.  A user cannot see hidden elements, which is why selenium can not see it.  Using ".getAttribute("innerHTML") allows selenium to find the innerHTML between the span element and it returns the text you want.